# It it possible to pin 'Run Java' and 'Debug Java' to the top bar in VSCode

Tags: java, visual-studio-code, editor

Other than creating a Keyboard Shortcuts , is it possible to pin the 'run java' & 'debug java' options to the top of VSCode instead of having it hidden behind the run button.

I have created a keyboard shortcut but I am just interested in having the buttons displayed at the top in the use cases i use them. I have explored VSCode , Java Debugger and Java Tester settings to find a related setting.

Comment: Are you using [`Java Extension Pack`](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=vscjava.vscode-java-pack)?

Comment: I am using both [Java Extension Pack](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=vscjava.vscode-java-pack) and [Language Support for Java(TM) by Red Hat](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=redhat.java)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [`Custom CSS and JS Loader`](https://github.com/be5invis/vscode-custom-css), it's a tool for **customizing the appearance of the Visual Studio Code** editor by applying custom CSS styles.

This extension allows you to **override the default styles of VS Code's interface elements**, so you can create a personalized theme for VS Code that aligns with your preferences.

With it you can inject buttons using JS!

See also: [How can I add custom CSS styles to VS Code?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75859763/how-can-i-add-custom-css-styles-to-vs-code/75860227#75860227)

Answer (score 1):

Visual Studio Code doesn't provide a built-in way to pin specific actions like "Run Java" or "Debug Java" directly to the top toolbar. The toolbar primarily displays the most frequently used actions and is not highly customizable in terms of adding new buttons directly to it.

The keyboard shortcut approach you've mentioned is one of the common ways to quickly trigger specific actions in VSCode, including running and debugging Java code.